# How do I override inline CSS with Class CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery to append an element such as:

```
var mytop=100;
$(this).appendTo('.container')
       .last()
       .wrap('<div class="action" style="top:' + mytop + 'px;"></div>');
```

Only `mytop` is a calculated number.  Since the new element has the class `action`, it should later change the top by adding a class `moveup`, such as:

```
$('document').on('click', function(e){
   if($(e.target).hasClass('action')){
      $(this).addClass('moveup');
   }
});
```

with the CSS as:

```
.moveup{
   top:5px;
}
```

The problem is, the inline CSS of the appended `<div>` overrides the class's CSS.  When this newly created item is clicked, it should have its top set at 5px.

How do I override the inline CSS with the Class's CSS?

Comment: `top:5px !important;` try

Comment: using `top:5px !important;` but be cautious when using too many `!important`

Comment: `if($(e.target).hasClass('action')){` - should not have `.` before the class name when using with `hasClass`

Comment: I swear I tried the `!important`, and it didn't work.  But retrying it does.  Too much coding for tonight... :/  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ArunPJohny, edited the question; it was a typo as I recreated the example problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-override-technique/

> The !important rule at the end of a value will override any other style declarations of that attribute, including inline styles.

```
p { 
    font-size: 24px !important; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried and it does work.  Thank you for your quick feedback.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Happy Coding..